# asp.net subdirectory sitemap

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, subdirectory

I have this configuration in my application.

~/sitemap.aspx
~/Web.sitemap
~/mobile/sitemap.aspx
~/mobile/Web.sitemap

"mobile" folder is not an application and I cannot convert it due to some reason. Thus no webconfig file is there.

What I want to do here is to use ~/mobile/Web.sitemap as the sitemap datasource for the treeview control in ~/mobile/sitemap.aspx.

When I place this code:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="MobileSiteMap" />
<asp:TreeView ID="trvSiteMap" runat="server" DataSourceID="MobileSiteMap" />
```

it loads ~/Web.sitemap instead of ~/mobile/Web.sitemap

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Add an entry to sitemap providers in your web.config that points to your mobile sitemap.

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Web.siteMap"/>
<add name="MyMobileSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/mobile/Web.sitemap"/>
</providers>
</siteMap>
```

2: Set the SiteMapProvider property of your MobileSiteMap DataSource to this newly added sitemap.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="MobileSiteMap"  SiteMapProvider="MyMobileSiteMapProvider" />
<asp:TreeView ID="trvSiteMap" runat="server" DataSourceID="MobileSiteMap" />
```